# Profile data won't save with extended Django User via Profile model with DRF and Djoser

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

My project is using Django Rest Framework, and Djoser. I'm attempting to create a Profile model with a one to one relationship with a user to store extra information about the user. My code looks like the following:

settings.py

```
DJOSER = {
  'SERIALIZERS': {
    'create_user': 'api.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'api.serializers.UserSerializer'
  }
}
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from api.models import *

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('city', 'state', 'zip', 'birth_date', 'user', 'id',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'profile',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I'm attempting to use the default routes provided by Djoser, and when I post to create a user, a profile object is created with a reference to the User object in the database. But, city/state/zip/birth_date are not actually populated with the submitted information. They're just blank.

Here is an example of the payload i'm testing with

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "abcdefgh",
    "profile": {
       "city": "Portland",
       "state": "OR",
       "zip": "12345"
    }
}
```

Endless google searching reveals example after example of what I've done here. I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

Halp.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py should be like this:

```
DJOSER = {
  'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'api.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'api.serializers.UserSerializer'
  }
}
```